# Endpoint is not getting read from clientconfig when deployed on server

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am trying to read endpoint from servicereferences.clientconfig file in my code like this:

```
public BaseRepository()
    {
        _proxy = new MyServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMyService");
        this.binding = (BasicHttpBinding)_proxy.Endpoint.Binding;
        this.endpoint = _proxy.Endpoint.Address;
    }
```

Here "BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" is the name of my endpoint as defined in Servicereferences.ClientConfig.

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

        <endpoint address="https://xxx/myservice.svc?wsdl"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
            contract="IMyserviceContract" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>


</system.serviceModel>
```

It works fine when I run it on local but doesn't work when I deploy it on server.
Am I missing something?

Comment: seems right now. But will just work ssl enabled server. You should switch it by protocol of endpoint address mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @ Davut Gürbüz It still doesn't work. The server is ssl enabled. I don't have any issue when I create the proxy client like this: _proxy = new xyzClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri)); in code and specify the URI manually.

Comment: Weird! I do it. You should look server logs where you publish. If you don't have rights,noway. Beside this depending on your configuration you can use your "_proxy" object directly what does this.binding set and this.endpoint DO. You can use your _proxy directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing your server is an Https SSL Secured server.

If so you should solve it by a small modification in your code.

In your binding there is an **EndpointAdrress** and as I remember there is a **Protocol** property on it it can be **"http"** or **"https"**.

If its https, binding has **SecurityMode** option it should be set as **Transport** which SSL uses.

For other scenarios you should open tracing by in you web.config

```
 <configuration>
 <system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
           <add name="traceListener" 
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
               initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
     </source>
  </sources>
```

Then call your service and open your **c:\log\Traces.svclog** with **SvcTraceViewer.exe** 
Inspect red logs.

Hope helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But as you can now see in the ClientConfig code the security mode being used is Transport only.

Comment: Can you access endpoint address manually for your server? The easiest way is using diagnostics. In your web config add related lines. You will see more details and real cause .

Comment: Yes. I can access endpoint address manually. When i create the proxyxlient like this: _proxy = new xyzClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));   ,I am able to access my service on server.

Comment: You may install IIS on your PC and test it. Sure this won't be deployment test. But it can give you a trick.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you read the endpoint configurations from the config then it will take all the default settings that you have done during adding the service reference. The default configuration contains the URI as below,

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkbenchService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
```

The above configuration takes your local server as the URI hence letting it to run in your local machine only.

If you want to deploy this into some other server then you need to specify the correct URI to locate your server and that can be done if you include the below code during creating the proxy.

```
Uri uri = null;
                if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
                {
                    hostName = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Host;
                    portNo = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Port;
                    if (hostName == "localhost")
                    {

                        uri = new Uri("http://localhost:2700/xyz.svc");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        uri = new Uri("http://" + hostName + ":" + portNo.ToString() + "/WebService/xyz.svc");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    uri = new Uri("http://localhost:2700/xyz.svc");
                }

                _proxy = new xyzClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
                _proxy.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(01, 20, 10);
                _proxy.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(01, 20, 10);
                _proxy.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(01, 20, 10);
                _proxy.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(01, 20, 10);

                return _proxy;
            }
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: So does it mean there is no way of reading the endpoint from ClientConfig file on server as only default endpoints can be read?

Comment: Also, When I debug it, I find it to be creating the endpoint with address which I define in the ClientConfig. I think it suggests that it can read any endpoint defined in the ClientConfig file and not just the default URI

Comment: yes @Raj it can read the endpoint whatever is defined in the endpoint and the reason I prefer doing this way is I don't have to remember the server I deploy my application and don't need to change the client config every time I deploy to other Servers. It automatically takes the server & selects the URI.